# Is it required to put comma after "doing smth" at the beginning of sentence?

Tags: punctuation, commas

Is it required to put comma after "doing something" at the beginning of sentence?

Examples:

(1) Conducting presentations(,) he showed the ability to confidently speak in public.

(2) Working with scientific materials(,) he actively used Chinese-language sources

Comment: Umary if you google **use of commas**, you will find numerous sites, including this one, that offer guidance on the subject.

Comment: "Conducting presentations" and "working with scientific materials" are both participial phrases. According to this site, If you start a sentence with a participial phrase, there should be a comma between it and the rest of the sentence. https://www.esu.edu/writing-studio/guides/participles.cfm

Comment: In written English, we don't write "smth" or "sb"; those abbreviations are only used in dictionaries to save space.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do some introductory words are always followed by a comma and others aren't?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/225276/why-do-some-introductory-words-are-always-followed-by-a-comma-and-others-arent)

Comment: An aside: sentences beginning with "-ing" structures, then followed by a full clause are almost always terrible style, these two included.

Comment: Doing something might require no comma.

Answer (score 1):

It is a good idea to punctuate after such introductory phrases.  It helps the reader locate the subject of the sentence, and it matches the intonation and rhythm of the spoken phrase.

In formal writing, commas after all but the shortest introductory phrases are required.